# C++: What is the use case of Lambda to function pointer conversion?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

You can convert Lambdas to function pointers. What are the practical use cases for this? Why do we need this?

[Play with it](https://godbolt.org/z/G2ZQ5o)

```
int main() {
    auto test = []() -> int { return 1; };
    using func_point = int (*)();
    func_point fp = test;
    return test();
}
```

Comment: you can pass it to library that expects function pointer

Comment: One word: Scopes.  It's a pain to have everything in the global scope.  A local lambda that is converted gets around this.

Comment: @Sergei That is a very useful example. Thank you

Comment: @NathanOliver Please explain

Comment: @User12547645 Lets say you need to register a callback, but this is a one off.  Before lambdas you had to define a function outside scope you are in to do this.  Having a converting lambda lets you do this inline instead and keeps an unneeded name out pf the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives to function pointers are std::function and template parameters / generic functors. All of those impact your code in different ways.

You can pass lambdas to code that expects either std::function, generic functors or function pointers. It is convenient to have a single concept in the calling code that supports all those different interface concepts so consistently and after all, convenience is all, lambdas are about.

Just to make this complete:

- function pointers are the least universal concept of the ones above, so not every lambda can be turned into a function pointer. The capture clause must be empty.
- Prefixing lambdas with a `+` explicitly casts them to a function pointer, if possible, i.e. in the following snippet, `f` has the type `int (*)( int )`:  `auto f = +[]( int x ) { return x; };`

Comment: Could you please give an example on how the prefix looks like? I think I have never seen that

Comment: @User12547645: Extended the answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can only convert lambdas with empty closure. Such lambdas are effectively stateless, which makes the conversion possible.

As for the use cases, one important use case is integration with C. There are plenty C APIs, which allow registration of user callbacks, usually taking one or more arguments, like this:

```
// Registers callback to be called with the specified state pointer
void register_callback(void (*callback)(void* state), void* state);
```

You can associate the state with a C++ class instance and translate the callback invokation to a method call:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void method();
};

Foo foo;
register_callback([](void* p) { static_cast< Foo* >(p)->method(); }, &foo);
```